# Unable to see my entry in the Event Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to write an entry into my own application log in the Windows EventViewer.

Here's my code

```
            string source = "MatrixTaskLaunch";
            string log = "MatrixTaskLauncher";
            string logevent = errorList.ToString();
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);

            EventLog.WriteEntry(source, logevent);
            EventLog.WriteEntry(source, logevent,
                EventLogEntryType.Warning, 234);
```

The first time I executed this code it executed the line

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);
```

and continued to step through, thereafter it skips this line and executes the remaining lines to completion, each time. Looking good! The indication is that it has created my log and is putting events in it.

However I can't see my log in the Win7 Event Viewer. The entries are neither under Application, nor in their own log (ie "MatrixTaskLauncher").

Have I missed something? I've tried refreshing the logs in Event Viewer, before someone suggests that!

Comment: Ok, I've got it - I need to instantiate my own EventLog object with the desired log name and use that instead of the static EventLog methods to write the entries.

Comment: No I haven't - it appears in the Custom Views under Administrative Events. Can sonmeone please point me to how I can create my own application log that appears as a separate log under "Application and Services Logs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me on Windows 7. What might be confusing is that the Windows Event Viewer doesn't load newly created event logs while it  is running (no matter how often you hit F5 or Refresh). After restarting the Windows Event Viewer loads earlier created application event logs and they appear in the plugin.

[image]

The windows eventlogs are backed by a file (at least in Windows 7) and those can be found at:

> C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs

After the call to `EventLog.CreateEventSource` the backing file appears in the folder among the other eventlog files:

[image]